# ALPACA Error when try to load a page

Tags: javascript, alpacajs

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).alpaca is not a function(…)

I AM GETTING AN ERROR when trying to load a html page with alpaca

```
    <!-- alpaca -->
    <script src="//code.cloudcms.com/alpaca/1.5.22/bootstrap/alpaca.min.js"></script>
    <link  href="//code.cloudcms.com/alpaca/1.5.22/bootstrap/alpaca.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="form"></div>
     <script type="text/javascript">

            $("#form").alpaca({
                "schema": {
                    "title":"User Feedback",
                    "description":"What do you think about Alpaca?",
                    "type":"object",
                    "properties": {
                        "name": {
                            "type":"string",
                            "title":"Name"
                        },
                        "feedback": {
                            "type":"string",
                            "title":"Feedback"
                        },
                        "ranking": {
                            "type":"string",
                            "title":"Ranking",
                            "enum":['excellent','ok','so so']
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    </script>
</body>
```

this is my codes.

i dont know what to do for the error.

pls help me to clear this error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

jQuery and Handlebars are dependencies for Alpaca. 
Updating the head to this should do the trick:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>My Little Alpaca Form</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.min.js"> </script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="//code.cloudcms.com/alpaca/1.5.22/bootstrap/alpaca.min.js"></script>
  <link  href="//code.cloudcms.com/alpaca/1.5.22/bootstrap/alpaca.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update the jquery version by replacing the line by this one

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Please be elaborative on how will updating the jquery version will fix the issue.